# Git Merge branches with different file structure

Tags: git, github, merge

I have a question regarding restructuring a git file structure and merge between new and old structure. The 'import_branch' is used to move source files from another verion control system to git. 'new_layout' is a restructuring of the source file three in git.

```
'import_branch'     ->      'new_layout'
- app/file1.txt     ->      - application/file1.txt
- fw/file2.txt      ->      - system/fw/file2.txt
```

**What I have done:**

- commited everything in 'import_branch'
- copied files to 'new_layout' (clean repository).
- git checkout 'new_layout'
- git mv app application
- git mv fw system/fw

**Now I want to merge changes in 'import_branch' to 'new_layout'**

- git checkout 'import_branch'
- let's say that there is a change to file app/file1.txt
- commit changes in 'import_branch'
- git checkout 'new_layout'
- git cherry-pick -x (latest 'import_branch' commit SHA)

this works, changes in 'app/file1.txt' are merged to 'application/file1.txt'

**Question**

However, if I add a new file in 'import_branch', say: 'fw/file3.txt' this will become 'fw/file3.txt' in 'new_layout' branch and not 'system/fw/file3.txt'. The link to the new file structure is not keept.

How to let git keep track of the old versus the new file structure during merges?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Couldn't you introduce a new commit to rename all files to the new location? Otherwise, you can amend the merge commit to move all leftover files to their new location.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This could of course be a soloution. However, I have have quite a large filetree, whith new files being added/edited in the old SCM system on a daily basis. So I was hoping for a soloution where I don't have to do to many manual operations...